# How to space a string from a customview in Android? (TabLayout)

Tags: android, xml, string, layout

I have a `TabLayout` with `ViewPager`.

I want to **always** space the text (string Conver...) from the white circle.. so it will work for any resolution

And when you receive a new message, the tab is updated with the amount of new messages: (see the image)

[CLICK HERE - IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMaky.png)

```
if(total_count == 0){
    this.tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setText(getString(R.string.str_chat));
} else if(total_count > 0) { 
    // if you have more than 0 messages then, reduce to Conver... 
    this.tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setText(getString(R.string.str_chat_reduced));
}
```

strings.xml

```
<string name="str_chat">CONVERSAS</string>
<string name="str_chat_reduced">CONVER...</string>
```

tab.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_home"
    tools:context="com.yvone.homer.HomeActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:paddingRight="5dp">

                <com.yvone.homer.customview.CustomFontView
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearance"
                    android:text=""
                    android:id="@+id/txtMatchBadge"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_white_badge"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/red_dark"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:paddingRight="5dp">

                <com.yvone.homer.customview.CustomFontView
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearance"
                    android:text=""
                    android:id="@+id/txtChatBadge"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_white_badge"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/red_dark"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution for you will be to provide your custom view for tab, containing `TextView` and `ImageView` by `tabForCustom.setCustomView(R.layout.your_custom_view)`.

When using viewPager you can also use `SpannableString` in overrided method `getPageTitle` of `PageAdapter class`:

```
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

            String tabName = "Section " + position;
            Drawable image = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_info_details);
            image.setBounds(0, 0, image.getIntrinsicWidth(), image.getIntrinsicHeight());
            SpannableString sb = new SpannableString(tabName + "x");
            ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(image, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
            sb.setSpan(imageSpan, tabName.length() - 1, sb.length()-1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            return sb;
}
```

And if u need just an icon - use `setIcon` method:

```
tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_info_details);
```

Also dont use another string resource to reduce length, provide elipsize property to TextView. More documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:ellipsize).